# TWRP loop after factory reset from stock android on moto m

Tags: factory-reset, twrp, stock-android, stock-rom

I just used the factory reset from the android backup and reset option to reset my moto m. But there seems to be a problem.

It automatically restarted into TWRP, so I did a factory reset from there from the wipe section. But after all this, I cannot boot into the OS. I have stuck in the twrp loop.

What I have understood is that the OS is looking for a return code from the recovery after which it can boot up but the custom recovery is not able to return that code which could earlier be returned by stock recovery.

And the phone does not even power off now!
Please help me

Thanks in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

it loops because it does not supports TWRP as the default android recovery of mobile. so try to flash the stock recovery image of your mobile after if you want to restore anything. and don't do any factory reset after flashing.